# click redirect from button to file input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Hey is there a smarter way to redirect a click from a `button` to `file input` element ?
Currently I'm using:

```
function clickRedirect() {
  document.getElementById("uploadFileButton").click();
}
```

Works. However I've been clearing any DOM manipulation (outside of appState) in my react project and this is the last bit remaining. I'd like to get rid of it.

Comment: does this helps you https://jsfiddle.net/432yz8qg/58/

Comment: It absolutely does!

Comment: adding as answer as well so you could mark it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ref with hidden button

```html
<input id="myInput" type="file" ref={(ref) => this.myInput = ref} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
<FloatingActionButton
  className="floatingButton"
  backgroundColor='#293C8E'
  onClick={(e) => this.myInput.click() }
  >
</FloatingActionButton>
```

attached demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/432yz8qg/58/